# How to use Emoji-mart in Laravel

Tags: laravel, emoji

Emoji-Mart https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart

i make js file in resource folder /resources/js/map.js

```
import 'emoji-mart/css/emoji-mart.css'
import { Picker } from 'emoji-mart'
```

add in webpack.mix.js

```
.js('resources/js/map.js', 'public/js')
```

Use

```
npm run dev
```

add include in my blade

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/map.js') }}"></script>
```

then try use in blade code from readme

```
<Picker set='apple' />
<Picker onSelect={this.addEmoji} />
```

But didnt see nothing

this is my first encounter with laravel mix, can you tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's an emoji picker component for React, yet you're trying to use it in Laravel?

Comment: @geertjanknapen oh i really missed this i thought i could use this via laravel-mix

Comment: I was just making sure, you seem to be able to do that, like so: https://adevait.com/laravel/using-laravel-with-react-js

I personally dont see a reason why you would though. Also there are other emoji packages, specifically for laravel, available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a emoji package which was built to run inside a Laravel application. You are using a react-based plugin which won't work this way.